# How do I train an AutoML model from parquet files?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Currently AutoML only supports BigQuery and CSV: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/classification-regression/create-dataset

Is there any way to train from [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) files (e.g. stored on GCS)?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way for doing this is by creating a BigQuery Table from the Parquet files. You can do this either by [loading the files](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet) into BigQuery which will create a copy, or by creating an [external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage) pointing to the files.